# C# to MusicXML?

Tags: c#, musicxml

Anyone know of any libraries that can be used to write MusicXML data from C#? Similar to this: http://proxymusic.kenai.com/ (although this one is for java).

I would try to not write it manually, but if worse comes to worst, I will have no choice but to output and write MusicXML manually from my results.

Answer (score 7):

Since MusicXML [has a XML schema available](http://www.recordare.com/musicxml/specification/xsd),
you can use [xsd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s.aspx) to create the classes that represent the XML structure:

```
xsd /c xlink.xsd musicxml.xsd container.xsd opus.xsd
```

Then you can use [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) to load and save the generated classes from/to files.

(For some reason, one of the schema files, osfpvg.xsd, wasn't able to compile correctly. Here's hoping you won't need it.)

Comment: as far as I know osfpvg.xsd is not one of the schema files.

Comment: from a visual studio command prompt i ran the following and it worked:
xsd /c musicxml.xsd xlink.xsd xml.xsd

Comment: I had to reverse the order here and do:

```xsd musicxml/schema/*.xsd /c```

FYI

Answer (score 1):

To use xsd.exe, you can use this command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\xsd.exe" "c:\dev\musicxml30\musicxml.xsd" "c:\dev\musicxml30\xlink.xsd" "c:\dev\musicxml30\xml.xsd" /c /o:"c:\dev"
```

Which will create a file called musicxml_xlink_xml.cs in the c:\dev folder.

[Compiled Class](http://goo.gl/Rfya5)

Answer (score 1):

For me when i tried to convert the `MusicXml3.0.xsd`, `xsd.exe` failed everytime. So, what i did was

```
xsd.exe musicFile.xml
```

which generated a schema file, and

xsd.exe musicFile.xsd /classes

which produced the required `c#` classes. The only thing i had to add in order for the generated xml to be read by programs like `Sibelius 7` was to add

```
<!DOCTYPE score-partwise PUBLIC "-//Recordare//DTD MusicXML 2.0 Partwise//EN" "http://www.musicxml.org/dtds/partwise.dtd">
```

And presto!