# Xsd to object class

Tags: c#, linq, oop, serialization, xsd

So, I'm trying to take an .xsd file (musicxml fixed standard), create an object class, use portions of it - specificially the note object - include it in a graph object, and then save both the graph object and a musicxml validated file.

All in all, the solutions I'm using have one or two massively breaking shortcomings.

Xsd2Code - Creates the file; but for some reason it makes a Items collection (of the type I need, ObservableCollection), and then an enumerable ItemsChoiceType[0-9] ObservableCollection.  The problem with the enumerable is after it generates, I have to either have to switch the latter to an Array, or do mumbo-jumbo for the XmlSerialisation attrs.  Generates a 2mb .cs file, so alot of code that would be autogenerated and would have to have a crapton of .extend.cs files to get it to fit.  Maybe I have to change some switches for it to work?  What switches fix this?

LinqToXsd / OpenLinqToXsd - Generates the file, hard codes it to reference a DLL file, then forces you to use List (no option to go to ObservableCollection), which doesn't have EditItem and can't be used for binding to WPF/XAML.  Otherwise, a bunch more .extend.cs files.

Altova C# generator - Expensive, requires a bunch of their DLLs to include in the project, messy.

---

Long story short, has anyone used any of these systems successfully and what did you have to do to shoehorn them?  What kind of pain will I have to deal with beyond the issues I'm having

---

I remember now for XSD.exe: XSD notation doesn't export, individual classes (such as 'note') don't serialise out to xml.  I would have to write out the entire thing from scorepartwise to every piece inbetween.  Which means I can't serialise a graph object that has 'note's as vertices.

Comment: Looks like the normal xsd.exe works for people? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567400/c-sharp-to-musicxml

Comment: I use WSCF Blue (http://wscfblue.codeplex.com/)

Comment: The link you posted is one of the ones I answered...  fairly certain it has the same problems as the Items/ItemsChoiceTypeN issue.  I'll give it a try using the 8.0A vs. the 7.0 xsd.exe.